# Memory allocator with custom pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, memory-management, standard-library

I tried to create a custom memory allocator which uses a smart pointer. I do not post the code because it's too big and doesn't add much of information. Then I tested it with a `std::vector`. It works perfectly well on Xcode. But when I tried to build the same code in Visual Studio 12 (2013), the build failed with the following error:

> ...vector(873): error C2660: '`std::_Wrap_alloc< my_allocator< int > >::construct`' : function does not take 2 arguments

the problem is in push_back method:

```
void push_back(value_type&& _Val)
    {
    ....
        this->_Getal().construct(this->_Mylast,
            _STD forward<value_type>(this->_Myfirst[_Idx]));
    ....
    }
```

The error message is a bit confusing. Real problem is that `this->_Mylast` is of type `my_allocator< int >::pointer`, which is a smart pointer, and construct method expects `int*`.

So, the question is simple: what are the requirements to pointer types used in a custom memory allocator? Should `X::pointer` be convertible to a raw pointer? If yes, it makes them pretty useless.

Actually I would expect that line of code to look like:

```
this->_Getal().construct(addressof(*(this->_Mylast)),
            _STD forward<value_type>(this->_Myfirst[_Idx]));
```

Let's try to find an answer in C++ standard, which says:

> [17.6.3.5-5] An allocator type X shall satisfy the requirements of CopyConstructible (17.6.3.1). The `X::pointer`, `X::const_pointer`, `X::void_pointer`, and `X::const_void_pointer` types shall satisfy the requirements of NullablePointer (17.6.3.3). No constructor, comparison operator, copy operation, move operation, or swap operation on these types shall exit via an exception. `X::pointer` and `X::const_pointer` shall also satisfy the requirements for a random access iterator (24.2)

If we take a look at NullablePointer reqs, they add few other requirements:

> [17.6.3.3] A NullablePointer type is a pointer-like type that supports null values. A type P meets the requirements of NullablePointer if:
>   (1.1) — P satisfies the requirements of EqualityComparable, DefaultConstructible, CopyConstructible, CopyAssignable, and Destructible...

If I check random access iterator requirements, I also don't find any explicit mentioning of its casting to a raw pointer. But in few places the approach with `addressof` is used (e. g. 24.2.1-5).

Also, it's not the only place in Microsoft's `std::vector` implementation where `X::pointer` and raw pointer are assumed to be equal. I'm wondering, what do I miss?

EDIT: I'll add a piece of my_allocator deffinition here:

```
class my_allocator
{
public:

typedef std::size_t          size_type;
typedef std::ptrdiff_t       difference_type;
typedef my_ptr<T>            pointer;
typedef my_ptr<const T>      const_pointer;
typedef T&                   reference;
typedef const T&             const_reference;
typedef T                    value_type;
typedef my_ptr<void>         void_pointer;
typedef my_ptr<const void>   const_void_pointer;

<constructors>

pointer allocate(size_type n, const_void_pointer = nullptr);
void deallocate(const pointer& ptr, size_type elements_num);
};
```

Comment: Can you provide us with all typedefs in your allocator? E.g. `const_pointer` and so forth? (It would absolutely not surprise me if VC++' standard library is not fully compliant)

Comment: Most likely VC++ standard library is buggy. I'd thought that construction of `std` contained objects should be done via `allocator_traits::construct` rather than directly `allocator::construct`.

Comment: @Columbo, I added the code you asked for.

Comment: @Walter, actually it does use allocator_traits. _Getal() returns a wrapper std::_Wrap_alloc< my_allocator< int > >.

Comment: Hello Maxym, were you able to run your allocator with custom pointer on VS STL finally? I try to build similar code on VS2015 and stuck on the same issue. I see boost/interprocess has dedicated set of containers to deal with such problem (it persists data in mem mapped file for instance), but I'd like to stick to minimal set of third party libs as possible...

Comment: No, I resorted to a workaround. It's obviously a bug, and, as far as I know, it's not fixed in VS2015 still. I didn't know about these workarounds in boost. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To solve this problem I created a `to_raw_pointer` function which happens to work on any "fancy pointer" which implements `operator->()`.  You can find it in the [libc++ implementation](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/memory).

Here it is:

```
template <class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_Tp*
__to_raw_pointer(_Tp* __p) _NOEXCEPT
{
    return __p;
}

template <class _Pointer>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
typename pointer_traits<_Pointer>::element_type*
__to_raw_pointer(_Pointer __p) _NOEXCEPT
{
    return _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(__p.operator->());
}
```

It works by calling the `operator->()` in an unconventional way.  This operator *must* either call another `operator->()`, or return a real pointer.  The overload for real pointers breaks the recursion with an identity function.  So this would be used like:

```
this->_Getal().construct(__to_raw_pointer(this->_Mylast),
            _STD forward<value_type>(this->_Myfirst[_Idx]));
```

`construct` is specified to take a real pointer, not a fancy pointer.  And there is no implicit conversion specified from fancy pointers to real pointers.  The container must use something such as `to_raw_pointer`, or `addressof`.

The container is also required to call `construct` via `allocator_traits`, instead of calling it directly on the stored allocator as shown.  This is to allow `construct` to be "defaulted" by `allocator_traits`, as opposed to requiring the allocator to implement `construct`.

Currently both `operator*()` and `operator->()` generally require the fancy pointer to be non-null prior to calling that operator on it.  However I am anticipating that this requirement will be relaxed for `operator->()` in the future.

**Update**

I was in a bit of a hurry when I wrote the above.  Now that I have the time, I was going to include the complete requirements on the `allocator::pointer` types.  However on re-reading the question I see that [Maxym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627327/maxym) has already done a good job of that in the question, so I won't repeat them here.

The one thing that is in the std, but is not completely obvious, is the implicit and explicit conversions among the four pointer types: `pointer`, `const_pointer`, `void_pointer`, and `const_void_pointer`:

```
implicit allocator pointer conversions:
+--------------------------------------+
| pointer      -->  const_pointer      |
|    |    \               |            |
|    |      ---------     |            |
|   \|/             _\|  \|/           |
| void_pointer -->  const_void_pointer |
+--------------------------------------+


explicit allocator pointer conversions:
+--------------------------------------+
| pointer           const_pointer      |
|   /|\                  /|\           |
|    |                    |            |
|    |                    |            |
| void_pointer      const_void_pointer |
+--------------------------------------+
```

That is, you can implicitly convert from non-`const` to `const`, and from non-`void` to `void`, and you can *explicitly* convert from `void` to non-`void`.  But there is no way for a container to `const_cast` (cast away `const`-ness) from an `allocator::const_pointer` or `allocator::const_void_pointer`.  Once the container goes `const`, it can never get back.

Comment: Cool, but it's actually the same as addressof(*(this->_Mylast)) because pointer indirection is anyway required by the standard. What I try to figure out is whether I do something wrong (because I misinterpret C++ standard) or it's a bug in VS STL implementation.

Comment: So, am I right to conclude that it's a bug in VC++ STL implementation? (Since X::pointer to raw pointer and vice versa is not allowed).

Comment: Yes: `construct` is specified to take a real pointer, not a fancy pointer. And there is no implicit conversion specified from fancy pointers to real pointers. The container must use something such as `to_raw_pointer`, or `addressof`.

Comment: Is this preferable to `addressof( * ptr )`? Neither `operator*` nor `operator->` are required, but `*` intuitively seems like a safer bet.

Comment: A subtlety is the question of whether you can dereference `ptr` or not.  If you can't, then obviously `addressof( * ptr )` won't work.  Currently the standard says that to use `operator->` with a `ptr` also requires that you be able to dereference `ptr`.  I believe the standard is too strict in this requirement.  *Only* if you select a member with `operator->` do you need to dereference.  If you call `ptr.operator->()`, `ptr` doesn't actually get dereferenced.  The standard should be clarified to say so.

Comment: OK. So `operator->` works with potentially null values, but `addressof` works with sloppier pointer implementations (and those not intended to support class types). `allocator_traits::allocate` can't return nullptr, so the current case might fall into the latter category.

Comment: Two points:  1.  If you ask `allocate` to allocate zero bytes, the result is unspecified (might not be dereferenceable).  2.  `vector::data()` is a prime candidate that will commonly need to convert a null allocator::pointer to a built-in pointer with maximal efficiency.  All that being said, for use with `construct`, I can not imagine a case where the `addressof` solution would not work just fine.